# Move pages to subdirectory in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, directory

I have a Homepage setup made with wordpress. 
All pages are in the root directory:

www.example.com/

is it possible to move some of my pages to a subdirectory ?

like:

www.example.com/products/

It is important that the root directory stays the same.

Comment: which are the pages you want to move ?

Comment: Moving pages to `example.com/products` would not be utilising a subdomain. A subdomain is formatted like this: `products.example.com`.  If you want to do this purely for aesthetic reasons you should consider using categories as they can generate the URL structure you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is simple way to do it.

Create a blank page in WordPress called "Products".

Then for all other pages, select "Products" page as "Parent" page.

Now new url of the page will be like:

yourrootdomain.com/products/page-name

Do the same for all pages you want under the "Products" base/directory slug.

Let me know if you cannot get it working or don't understand it or it does not solve your issue.

Here is how to select Page's parent in page attributes section on add or edit page screen:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-attributes/#parent

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to set the pages as a subdirectory exactly as I wanted to. But now the pages are displayed automatically as submenus in the website. I just wanted change the directory. The reason for that is easy: I have a module that uses permalinks to display projects and I had to change the links to get other pages and not projects. Here is the full tutorial I have used: http://www.eleganttweaks.com/divi/change-divi-projects-url-permalink/

Comment: @jublikon Glad it worked for you. If you have access to theme files, where menu is being created, if you find, wp_list_pages() , add depth=1 into it and child pages will not show up there. <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>

Comment: @Asadullah can you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76149074/need-pages-in-subdirectories-in-wordpress-with-same-page-names)?